# URL redirection issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, redirect

URL redirection is not working i.e

I am using filter for replacing string which match with my anchor tag.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yg5gaos1/186/)

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

app.filter('parseUrlFilter', function ($sce) {
    var urlPattern = /(^|\s)((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)/gi;
    return function (text, target, otherProp) {
           text = text.replace(urlPattern, '<a target="' + target + '" href="$&">$&</a>');
           return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
});

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.text = 'Example text http://example.com http://example.com http://google.com google.com';
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
     <p ng-bind-html="text | parseUrlFilter:'_blank'"></p>
</div>
```

My problem is when url having http or https then it redirect us correctly to respective page i.e if  **"http://google.com"** **it works properly**. But if 
http or https is missing then it does not work properly i.e if **google.com** **it doesn't** redirect to google.com instead it redirect to localhost/folder/google.com.

Comment: that's because href needs a protocol if the url is absolute otherwise it is considered relative to the current one

Comment: Could you please tell me solution for this?